# Torn Michelin Pro4 Endurance tire

Tags: tire

Used bike (no apparent wear on the tires), this happened after about 300km of riding of my own.

Front tire: [image]

Rear tire: [image]

Why do you think this happened? Is it safe to use the rear tire further?

Comment: I would guess that these tires are at least 5 years old and degraded without having being used. You are asking for trouble by continue to use them.

Comment: I'm quite sure Pro 4's have not been made for 5 years.

Comment: I think the tires were rotten.   Age, sunlight, ozone, petroleum fumes.

Comment: Your best plan now is to replace both tyres and both tubes, and all four brake pads.  It could be worthwhile to inspect the BB for a overhaul/clean/grease as well as the wheel bearings.  This bike has sat unused for far too long.   Your brake/gear cables might benefit from a replace too, depending on how smooth they shift/pull.

Comment: Did you ride near a chemical plant? Or run over a xenomorph? Perhaps some kind of corrosive substance got on them?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I _did_ run over a xenomorph once. This must be it!